# Equivalent of MATLAB `clf` in R

Tags: r, matlab

How do you clear the plot in R without closing the device, like with the command `clf` in MATLAB?

Comment: You mean like clearing all the plots in RStudio?

Comment: I use R with emacs, say with the command line

Comment: Do you mean `plot.new()`?

Comment: @BrianDavis no, I found a command behaving like `clf`: `plot(NULL)`